# Merge data frames on multiple common values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to `merge` two data frames based off common values. The problem is there are duplicate values. I'm trying to merge the values based on the first appearance. I want to merge on values in `Col B` & `Col C`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : ['10:00:05','11:00:05','12:00:05','13:00:05','14:00:05'],
    'B' : ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','DEF'],          
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,2],            
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : ['10:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','14:00:00'],
    'B' : ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','DEF'],         
    'C' : [1,1,1,2,2],          
    })
```

If I try:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, on = ["B", "C"])
```

Output:

```
        A_x    B  C       A_y
0  10:00:05  ABC  1  10:00:00
1  13:00:05  ABC  1  10:00:00
2  11:00:05  DEF  1  11:00:00
3  12:00:05  XYZ  1  12:00:00
4  14:00:05  DEF  2  14:00:00
```

Whereas my intended output is:

```
          A    B  C         D
0  10:00:05  ABC  1  10:00:00
1  11:00:05  DEF  1  11:00:00
2  12:00:05  XYZ  1  12:00:00
3  13:00:05  ABC  1          
4  14:00:05  DEF  2  14:00:00
```

Comment: @Rushabh Mehta, This is nothing like that question? Could you please take another look. Your flag is blocking my question

Comment: Yea, I flagged the wrong question. However, this is most definitely a duplicate question.

Comment: @RushabhMehta, well could you attach the right question??

Comment: Working on it right now

Comment: And I'm a little curious as to why you seem rather flustered by my flagging

Comment: Not at all. Just hoping to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` and then `duplicated` + `loc` to update your merged column:

```
merge_cols = ['B', 'C']

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, on=merge_cols)

df2.loc[df2[merge_cols].duplicated(), 'A_y'] = ''

print(df2)

        A_x    B  C       A_y
0  10:00:05  ABC  1  10:00:00
1  13:00:05  ABC  1          
2  11:00:05  DEF  1  11:00:00
3  12:00:05  XYZ  1  12:00:00
4  14:00:05  DEF  2  14:00:00
```